# Copy data from a given filename/path vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an excel tool where it would extract data from a given filename(workbook). Let's say, on my main workbook in(Sheet1-Cell A1), users will enter the filename. Then on a cmdbutton click, it'll copy the data from that specific filename(workbook).

I have created a file that copies data from another workbook, however, it indicates the specific path & filename of the workbook where the data will be copied.

```
Dim myData As Workbook
Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Book2.xlsx")

Call Sample
Selection.Copy
```

What I want, is to allow users to just enter the filename, then excel will locate that file, select data from there & copy it on the main workbook(Sheet2).

Comment: `allow users to just enter the filename, then excel will locate that file, select data from there & copy it on the main workbook(Sheet2)` that's great. What part of your code isn't working towards that goal?

Comment: @findwindow -- I don't have any codes for this specific function yet. This is my first time working on this. What I know is that, these codes will work on what I want to happen: ( 'Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName' & 'ActiveWorkbook.Name' ); however, I'm not sure how to work on it. :(

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. We help with _specific_ coding errors/issues. You need to write the code then come back when you get stuck with a particular step. Hint: try `filesystemobject`

Comment: Oh, ok. thanks for the hint! I'll be back once I have my codes on this. :)

Comment: Update OP with the question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured something out

```
Sub copydata()

Dim path As String
path = InputBox("Please input path")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim actualfile As Workbook
Set actualfile = ActiveWorkbook

Dim script As Object
Set script = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim catalogue As Object
Set catalogue = script.GetFolder(path)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

Dim textfile As Object
For Each textfile In catalogue.Files

    Workbooks.Open textfile

    Dim loadedfile As Workbook
    Set loadedfile = ActiveWorkbook

    loadedfile.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Copy

    actualfile.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").Offset(1, 0).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    loadedfile.Close Savechanges:=False

Next textfile

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
```

End Sub

The only problem though is, it copies data to the column after the heading instead of copying it to the row below the heading - help on this is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: It's still the same. :(

Comment: Ok, so my heading is on the 1st row, columns A to J. It pastes from column K onwards. It's supposed to be pasted below the heading (next empty row)

Comment: Try `actualfile.WorkSheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).PastesSpecial....` Edit: or really `actualfile.WorkSheets(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial...` should work too.

Comment: You're welcome. A few notes. If you're only copying values, consider setting ranges to each other. And I think you asked about using `currentregion` previously. Try to avoid that, instead specifying the ranges explicitly. Good job on coding almost all of it yourself ^_^

Comment: I am happy to help those who put in effort.